# Spacing between several superscripts mboxes

Tags: math-mode, spacing, superscripts

I'm getting a small extra space between two superscripts in separate math objects.

MVE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
zz$\mbox{zz}^{\mbox{a,a,}}$$^{\mbox{a,a}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

There's no extra space between math texts **zz** and **zz** (marked as red 1), but there is a small one between superscripts mboxes (marked as red 2). How can I get rid of that space?

Comment: Would it be possible to construct it as `zz$\mbox{zz}^{\mbox{a,a,}\mbox{a,a}}$` or`zz$\mbox{zz}^{{\mbox{a,a,}}{\mbox{a,a}}}$`, or are the separate `$...$` math groupings provided by some external program?

Comment: Just to know: why are you splitting it into 2 boxes?

Comment: It's not normal to use `\mbox` in a superscript (it prevents the contents being script size)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

It's `\scriptspace`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\showoutput


zz$\mbox{zz}^{\mbox{a,a,}}$$^{\mbox{a,a}}$

\scriptspace=0pt
zz$\mbox{zz}^{\mbox{a,a,}}$$^{\mbox{a,a}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\scriptspace` isn't shown by `\showoutput`, it's just added to the width of the box containing the superscript. Rules 18b, 18c and 18d in Appendix G.

Comment: @egreg yes true I'd just added `\showoutput` as more or less the first thing I always do to a supplied MWE before running it locally:-)

Comment: Finally!! I couldn't find it. I was looking all the tracing output and didn't understand what is this space.

Answer (score 5):

Each `^{...}` adds a small horizontal space after the superscript; the width is controlled by the `\scriptspace` parameter, having a default value of 0.5pt.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

zz$\mbox{zz}^{\mbox{a,a,}}$$^{\mbox{a,a,}}$X

\scriptspace=0pt
zz$\mbox{zz}^{\mbox{a,a,}}$$^{\mbox{a,a,}}$X

\scriptspace=5pt
zz$\mbox{zz}^{\mbox{a,a,}}$$^{\mbox{a,a,}}$X

\end{document}
```

[image]

See Rules 18b, 18c and 18d in Appendix G of the TeXbook.

How to cope with this depends on your real intentions, which are far from clear.

Comment: @Linuxss Modules 757, 758 and 759 in `tex.web`. See also section 23.2.1 in TeX by Topic.